# python using the loop and input user name

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

How to code a loop that asked user to input several student name and print out the name.

1st the use is requested to input how many student name to enter and it loops the number enter asking for the student name.

Please see the code below. My challenge is to include in the loop.

```
n = eval(input("How many student do you have to enter: "))
a = (input("Enter the student name: "))

print (a)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
students = []
n = int(input('How many student do you have to enter:'))
for x in range(n):
    name = input('Enter the student name:')
    dob = input('Enter the student dob:')
    students.append({'name': name, 'dob': dob})
print('\n'.join(['name: {0}\ndob: {1}'.format(x.get('name'), x.get('dob')) for x in students]))
```

Comment: Why not use a `for` loop? Manually incrementing a counter in a `while` is more likely to attract typos or off-by-one errors.

Comment: Good idea :) updated

Comment: how do you add another DOB input?

Comment: This is great! thank you!